# Subdomain route to subfolder with htaccess on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I am trying to create a subdomain `sub.domain.com` that displays `domain.com/sub` without changing the address bar.

I've come up with the following .htaccess rule based on other questions made here:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ /sub/$1 [L,NC]
```

The problem is I'm using a WordPress instance and my .htaccess currently looks like this now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ /sub/$1 [L,NC]
```

But when I browse sub.domain.com I'm being redirected to my homepage (domain.com) from WordPress. How can I do this correctly?

---

Tried to change it to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*)$ /sub/$1 [NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

But it is still not working

Comment: That rule should come before the wordpress rules and it should not have the `L` flag set.

Comment: @arkascha edited the question, tried your solution but it is not working

Comment: Can you check your Cpanel settings and also check the site address

Comment: @Pratikbhatt I'm not using cPanel, I'm on Amazon AWS Lightsail with a Bitnami WordPress instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a virtual host in apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub
</VirtualHost>
```

Or `VirtualDocumentRoot` if mod_vhosts_alias is enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

In above I am pointing it to /sub directory if it exists. After all changes restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can add below line of code in your wp-config.php files

```
define('WP_HOME','http://sub.domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://sub.domain.com');
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the wordpress domain, I want to have my wordpress in my main domain and a custom subdomain displaying contents from a subfolder on my webserver